# identify the hardware device using java

Tags: java, ipad, device

I have developed a web application.Same user(same login id) can login to the system by using multiple devices. I want to identify the devices seperately. The devices can be ipads,tabs etc...
As an example, there can be 3 ipads .So I need to uniquely identify which ipad was used to login. I need to implement this using java.

Thank you in advance

Comment: So... what is your question exactly? Be specific.

Comment: I wanted to know whether there is  a way(using java ) to identify the hardware device after user logged to the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really identify each device uniquely because device does not send any type of unique identifier to server.

The typical solution is using cookie. You can create cookie that identifies you each device when it connect first time. The cookie may (for example) take into consideration the client IP, user-agent, timestamp and some random part or, alternatively just create `UUID`. The cookie should be persisted and never expired.

Now, every time the client connects it sends the cookie and you can identify it. 
If you want to detect the device type use `User-Agent` HTTP header. This will allow you to limit number of devices of the same type as you want.

Obviously user can delete cookie from his browser or use other browser. This is the reason that I mentioned in the beginning of my answer: you cannot *really* identify the device uniquely. You can however do the best effort explained above.

Answer (score 0):

*I think you can use method

> java.lang.System.getProperty(String)
>   The blow two property be concated will ok.

```
 * <dt>os.name              <dd>Operating System Name
 * <dt>user.name            <dd>User account name*
```

the above is error.

**You cat get client identifier by javascript .java is working with server.**

Comment: IMHO OP wants to identify client device at server side, so system property is not too relevant here.